# Relationship between constants in an equation

Tags: exponential-function, transcendental-equations

I have the following equation:

$e^{ax} + e ^{bx} = e ^{cx}$

Is it possible to find a relationship between constants $c$ and $a$, $b$ that holds for all $x$'s?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. It will never hold for $x=0$.

Comment: So trivial! I was just about to answer that a family of distinct exponential functions is linearly independent and you come up with simply plugging in $x=0$ :)

Comment: i could assume that $x$ can never take the value of $0$. Is it still impossible to find such a relationship @HagenvonEitzen ?

Comment: Both sides are continuous functions of $x$. If it doesn't hold at $x=0$, then there are numbers close to $0$ for which it also doesn't hold.